# What conditions guarantee that a function is bounded by these two "best-fit" parabolas?

Tags: calculus, quadratics, curves, upper-lower-bounds, plane-curves

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable function. Define the **left (right) best-fit parabola** as follows:

The left [right] best-fit parabola is the quadratic function $p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ such that $p(a)=f(a),p(b)=f(b)$, and $p'(a)=f'(a)$ $\big[p'(b)=f'(b)\big]$.

A bit of algebra reveals that there is exactly one choice of coefficients $A,B,C$ (for each parabola) that makes the definition work. You can get a visual of these parabolas on this [Desmos module](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cfntisebzl) and play around with them.

My question is, under what conditions do these two parabolas create upper and lower bounds for $f$ on $[a,b]$? Some experimentation in the above Desmos module reveals that this is often the case, but not always. For example, it is not the case for $f(x)=\tanh(x)$, shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/afmfouihsg), even on intervals that are increasing and concave down.

These counterexamples seem to occur when the third derivative changes sign on the interval (as in the above case). So my suspicion is that the parabolas bound the function if the third derivative does not change sign on the interval. Is this conjecture valid, and if so, can someone help me prove it?

Comment: The derivative of $f$ being convex or concave is a sufficient but not a necessary condition, since tangent lines of a convex function are always below the function. Convexity or concavity of a differentiable function follows from its second derivative (so, the third derivative of $f$).

Comment: Is it your intention that (in the current version of your question) the $a,b$ in $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ are the same as the $a,b$ in $[a,b]$ or $p(a)=f(a)$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Nope that was a mistake—just fixed it.

Comment: @LinAlg I'm not seeing your logic. The derivative of either parabola is not in general a tangent line to the function, since the second derivative of the parabolas does not necessarily agree with that of the function at points $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @WillG you are right! Then an extra condition is that the second derivative at $a$ or $b$ should be at least (or at most) 2

Comment: @WillG I think I know how to prove it but it is a nightmare :D. You start with $y''' = z \geq 0$, integrate it 3 times, then bound it from both sides, then solve for coefficients of the bounding functions and simplify. You will likely be left with two inequalities involving integrals of $z$. If the conjecture holds, it should be possible to rearrange the resulting inequalities into a true statement

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the converse. Below are the bounds for $\sin (2\pi x)$ and $\cos (2\pi x)$. As can be seen, both of them change the sign of the 3rd derivative, however, sin is bound and cos is not. So, clearly, your conjecture is not a necessary criterion. I still need to think over if it is sufficient

[image]

[image]

Here's another example I came up with

$$y(x) = (x-0.5)^5$$ and

$$y(x) = (x-0.5)^5 + 0.001 * \mathcal{N}(\frac{x-0.5}{0.001})$$

where $\mathcal{N}$ is the standard normal distribution. As can be seen, both functions are bound, but the latter changes sign in the 3rd derivative, while the former does not.

[image]
[image]

I can't seem to come up with a counter-example to the sufficiency criterion by trial and error. Perhaps it does hold. Here's an attempt to prove it. I will present as far as I get, perhaps somebody has an idea on how to continue

WLOG, assume that the interval of interest is $[0,1]$. We will use two bounding functions

$$f_1(x) = A_1 x^2 + B_1 x + C_1$$
$$f_2(x) = A_2 x^2 + B_2 x + C_2$$

The constraints are

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  f_1(0) &=& C_1 = f(0) \\
  f_1(1) &=& A_1 + B_1 + C_1 = f(1) \\
  f_1'(0) &=& B_1 = f'(1) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  f_2(0) &=& C_2 = f(0) \\
  f_2(1) &=& A_2 + B_2 + C_2 = f(1) \\
  f_2'(1) &=& 2A_2 + B_2 = f'(1) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Solving the above constraints, we obtain

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_1(x) &=& [f(1) - f(0) - f'(0)]x^2 + f'(0) x + f(0)\\
f_2(x) &=& [f(0) - f(1) + f'(1)]x^2 + [2f(1) - 2f(0) - f'(1)]x + f(0)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This is where I get stuck. Why assuming $f(x)$ to be a 3rd anti-derivative of either positive or negative function enable it to be bound by some simple function of its endpoints. I feel like this idea resembles [mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and [Green's theorem and/or Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), but neither really fits directly

Comment: Very nice plots! I wasn't really expecting it to be a necessary condition, by way of analogy with the fact that a function lies above its tangent lines if (but not only if) it is concave up.

Comment: @WillG I can send you the code in python. It calculates the derivatives numerically, so you can use any function you want